# in a pandas DF with 'season' (season1, season2...) columns, 6 months or ~182 days needs to be added to the last season that's not null

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas DF with multiple seasons and for each row, I need to add 6 months (~182 Days) to the last season that's not null.The dates are `dtype: datetime64[ns]`.

`df`:

```
    S1          S2             S3
2020-12-31      naT            naT
2020-12-31      naT            naT
2020-12-31    2020-12-31       naT
2020-12-31    2020-12-31    2021-01-31
```

Desired Output:

```
   S1            S2             S3
2021-06-30      naT            naT
2021-06-30      naT            naT
2020-12-31    2021-06-30       naT
2020-12-31    2020-12-31    2021-07-31
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to find if the next cell in the row is NaT and then use [pd.DateOffset()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) to add extra months to those cells:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

text = """
S1            S2             S3
2020-12-31    naT            naT
2020-12-31    naT            naT
2020-12-31    2020-12-31     naT
2020-12-31    2020-12-31     2021-01-31
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), header=0, sep='\s+')
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')

# find in which cells the next value is na
next_value_in_row_na = df.shift(-1, axis=1).isna()

# for each cell where the next value is na, try to add 6 months
df = df.mask(next_value_in_row_na, df + pd.DateOffset(months=6))
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
    S1          S2          S3
0   2021-06-30  NaT         NaT
1   2021-06-30  NaT         NaT
2   2020-12-31  2021-06-30  NaT
3   2020-12-31  2020-12-31  2021-07-31
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help!